# Scheduled Notifications Triggers Every Time I Open App

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I am building an app which triggers a notification at 11:30 IST..I have Tested It Its Working But After 11:30 Whenever i open my app it issues a notification...

i don't know why i think it should be some error in condition in time checking...

i want notification to be triggered on time only once in a day...and then the next day...:)

please resolve this 
thanks in advance

```
**MainActivity.java**

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
spinner = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReciever.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent   = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,0,intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}


**AlarmReciever.java**

package com.alivestats.alivestats;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int MID = 1;

    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.background)
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText("description").setSound(alarmSound)
            .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
    notificationManager.notify(MID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
    MID++;

}

}
```

Comment: which <intent-filter> you have given to your BroadcastReceiver, while registering it in manifest.?

Comment: How did you get time to 11:30 ?

Comment: i have just put  <receiver android:name="com.android.app.AlaramReceiver"/>

Comment: RTC_WAKEUP ->ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP

Comment: means ? @tinysunlight

Comment: Try this..<receiver
            android:name="com.android.app.AlaramReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":remote">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NOTIFY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: Try  intent.setAction("repeating") and check action in onReceive. and set android:exported to false in mainfest.

Comment: I think it just because you didn't add a action.

Comment: I think other app can trigger your AlarmReciever .

Comment: @MaheshB your code is not working..:(

Comment: can you edit and give me the code ?? @tinysunlight

Comment: I added a answer .But I never use a alarm,It's just my guess.I think you should setAction  and add log action on onReceive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After So Much Of Tea and Coffee i coded the answer myself...

```
long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
if (t <= calendar.getTimeInMillis()) {
        //calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 6); //add 6 days.
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReciever.class);
        intent1.setAction("NOTE");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        //am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }

    else{

    }
```

i have just compared system time to the notification time..if notifcation time is less than equal to system time its true and reciever will work..but if not then nothing will happen...

BTW thanks for helping @tiny and @Mahesh

Comment: What happen if user open app for first time in 11:31:00 and reopen app after two day  .. in this case alarm manager  will never work  and notification will not show in 11:30:00 after one day ...

Comment: @MahmoodAli the notification manager is running in background..so it doesn't matter until background service is stopped manually or due to some crash..or other reason..notification will be issued every time after 11:31:00(first open time) on next occurence of 11:30:00 AM.. be it any day..:)

Comment: What i mean is that  am.set(...) should be executed at least once time  to registered intent for it broadcast by the system,  when user open app for first time in 11:31:00 this line of code will not execute so the Intent will not registered and onReceive in AlarmReceiver will not fire in next  occurrence of 11:30:00 AM so notification will never issued . sorry for my bad English and i wish you understand what i mean

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReciever.class);
intent1 .setAction("ilove");


public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 if(!"ilove" .equalsIgnoreCase(getAction()))log.e("test",intent.getAction());
}


<receiver android:name="com.android.app.AlaramReceiver" android:exported="false">
 <intent-filter>
<action android:name="ilove" /> 
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: where to put onRecieve() function in MainActivity or AlarmReciever ??@tiny

Comment: It's just in your AlarmReciever .

Comment: you just need to add Action in  where you create PendingIntent  and  check Action before you show notificatin.

Comment: Still Facing Same Problem :( Notification Triggered...:( @tiny

Answer (score 0):

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

```
          calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 6);

    int myPreferedTime=calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);


    Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();

    int currentHour = rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    Log.i("current time","is"+currentHour);


    int difference=myPreferedTime-currentHour;

    Log.i("Differencevalue","is"+difference);

    switch(difference)
    {
        case 1:

            rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
            break;

        case 2:

            rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
            break;

        case 3:

            rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
            break;

        case 4:

            rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);
            break;

        case 5:

            rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
            break;
        case 6:

            rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
            break;

        case -1:
            rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,23);
            break;

        case -2:
            rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,22);
            break;

        case -3:
            rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,21);
            break;
        case -4:
            rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,20);
            break;
        case -5:
            rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,19);
            break;

        case -6:
            rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,18);
            break;
        case -7:
            rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,17);
            break;
        case -8:
            rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,16);
            break;
        case -9:
            rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,15);
            break;
        case -10:
            rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,14);
            break;
        case -11:
            rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,13);
            break;
        case -12:
            rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,12);
            break;
        case -13:
            rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,11);
            break;
        case -14:
            rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,10);
            break;
        case -15:
            rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,9);
            break;

        case -16:
            Log.i("am here","bcoz time is 11 clock");
            rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
            break;

        case -17:
            rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,7);
            break;
        case -18:
            rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,6);
            break;
        default:
            break;


    }

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent1, 0);
        Log.i("am sending", "yes");
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Log.i("time holding with me", "calendar stores time like" + rightNow.getTimeInMillis());
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, rightNow.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: i worked for a week to overcome the problem of scheduled-notifications-triggers-every-time-i-open-app and providing this solution if anyone have doubts please let me know

Comment: Please provide more information to your answer. Just adding a script is not enough.

Comment: in the above script i am doing the math calculation  majorly am making difference between current hour and myprefered hour  and based on difference value am decide to add hours to the app so that it will toast a notification at every morning in between 6:00(A.M)-(7:00)

Answer (score 0):

To prevent an Alarm from continually triggering each time the App is launched (after the alarm time has passed), the following can be added:

```
    Calendar timeNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    if(calendar.before(timeNow)){
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    mAlarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, mAlarmPendingIntent);
```

I found the above example [here](http://droidmentor.com/schedule-notifications-using-alarmmanager/). The time now is checked against the Alarm time and if the Alarm time is before the time now then another day is added to the alarm. 
Hopefully this helps :) .

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem & tried every suggestions on this page though, I couldn't fix my problem. Here is the proposed solution for this problem and it works for me.

**Register the receiver in manifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.DayAlarmReceiver"/>
```

**Set the alarm manager**

```
public void setDayAlarm(Context context) {

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);

AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, DayAlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent.putExtra("HOUR_OF_DAY", 4);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 5555, alarmIntent, 0);
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
Log.d("Set the day alarm");
}
```

**Check intent extras in onReceive() method of the receiver class**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  int setHour = intent.getIntExtra("HOUR_OF_DAY", -1);
  Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
  int currentHour = rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

  if(currentHour == setHour){
    Log.d("This is perfect, Trigger the alarm");
    showNotification(context, msg);
  }else{
   Log.d("This is perfect, Trigger the alarm");
 }
```