# Alarm Manager daily repeat works uncorrectly

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I want to Start two services at different times in daily period in my app. for this purpose I use `AlarmManager` in my `SplashActivity` and with `SharedPreferences` I fix that this `AlarmManager` run just for the first time that app opening.
I uses this codes:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    //Check if first run, start alarms
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("init", MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (preferences.getBoolean("firstTime", true)) {
        startCheckService(getApplicationContext());
        startMorningService(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstTime", false);
        editor.apply();

    }
```

and this is alarm's method:

```
public void startCheckService(Context c){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,23);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(c,0,new Intent(c,CheckService.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) c.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.cancel(pi);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,pi);
}

public void startMorningService(Context c){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,8);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(c,0,new Intent(c,CheckTodayEvents.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) c.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.cancel(pi);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,pi);
}
```

but my problem. every time I open my app, alarmManager run and my services do run. why? how can I solve this?

Comment: What is our targetSdkVersion?

Comment: it is 25 @Sagar

Comment: I try https://stackoverflow.com/a/34089307/4620449 but still not solved

Comment: Try setting the DAY as well (each time the alarm is stopped, re-set it 24 hours later by adding one full day).

Comment: @KlingKlang how can I set day? `calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));`? I use this but not solved.

Comment: each time the alarm stopped means use am.set instead of am.setRepeating inside my service?

Comment: Yes, use set. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9629095/2649012) should work.

Comment: I use set but alarmManager run by app open again @KlingKlang I think this is a bug

Comment: Did you try the link I posted?

Comment: I use Broadcast receiver instead of service and my problem is resolved

Comment: Great. Now my suggestion is to post an answer with your solution and accept it, so that this post will be removed from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution. Only thing to do is change `Service` And `getService()` of PendingIntent to `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public static void startCheckService(Context c){

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,23);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    if(calendar.getTimeInMillis() >= Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()) {

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, 0, new Intent(c, CheckService.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) c.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTime().getTime(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
    }
}
```

I don't know why but my problem is resolved.